# Con qué puedo remplazar el startActivityForResult en android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial del año pasado en youtube para crear una app de notas. En el tutorial se me pide que use  startActivityForResult pero android studio me dice que está obsoleto. Como puedo reemplazarlo?. A continuación les dejo el codigo.

```
`startActivityForResult(
                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateNoteActivity.class),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ADD_NOTE
            );`
```

Answer (score 0):

`starctActivityForResult(Intent, Int)` **no esta marcado como deprecado** hoy en día en la referencia de Android.[[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))] Sin embargo en una guía[[2](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)] dice:

> While the underlying startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() APIs are available on the Activity class on all API levels, it is strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX Activity and Fragment.

> Mientras que las APIs `startActivityForResult()` y `onActivityResult()` estan disponibles en la clase `Activity` en todos los niveles de API, esta fuertemente recomendado usar las APIS de Resultado de Actividades introducidas en AndroidX `Activity` y `Fragment`.

En particular en `androidx.activity` sí esta deprecada la funcion que usas y menciona[[3](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))]:

> This method is deprecated. Use `registerForActivityResult( ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback)` passing in a `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult` object for the `ActivityResultContract`.

> Este metodo esta deprecado. Use `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback)` pasando un objeto `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult` para el `ActivityResultContract`.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para documentar lo que preguntas se puede diferenciar la forma anterior y la actual:

**1) Forma anterior**

Se manda abrir una Activity, enviando un código:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);
```

Este código espera ser recibido dentro del método `onActivityResult()` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 12345) {
        //* Realiza alguna tarea.
    }
}
```

**2) Nueva Forma.**

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    //Revisa requestCode
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                   //* Realiza alguna tarea.

                }
            }
        });
```

Se manda abrir una Activity:

```
    mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class));
```

Esto lo puedes revisar en la documentación:

[Cómo obtener un resultado de una actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @MarkoSotola recuerda marcar como solución si la respuesta ayudo a resolver el problema , revisa [tour], saludos.