# startActivityForResult y onActivityResult obsoletos

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tengo un pequeño problema y es que tengo el siguiente contenido:

```
    private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_GALLERY)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == RC_GALLERY){
                mPhotoSelectedUri = data?.data
                mBinding.imgPhoto.setImageURI(mPhotoSelectedUri)
                mBinding.tilTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                mBinding.tvMessage.text = getString(R.string.post_message_valid_tittle)
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen, los métodos de `startActivityForResult()` y `onActivityResult` han quedado obsoletos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cómo hacer para poder adaptar esta parte del código a algo que no esté obsoleto. He buscado por internet pero no me queda del todo claro.

¿Me podéis echar un cable?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta duplicada de: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/482911/302

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin

Tu código debe cambiar a :

```
val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        // Handle the Intent
        if(requestCode == RC_GALLERY){
            mPhotoSelectedUri = intent?.data
            mBinding.imgPhoto.setImageURI(mPhotoSelectedUri)
            mBinding.tilTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mBinding.tvMessage.text = getString(R.string.post_message_valid_tittle)
        }
    }
}
```

para iniciar el Intent :

```
 private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startForResult.launch(intent)
    }
```